# Check which user clicked on which link

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink

I have few links on my website, how can I record into database which user clicked on which link. I have records of the links into database and users. I have created a table in which there will be userid, linkid. But im not sure how to code this php. Any ideas?

EDIT:

```
<a hef="page.php?id=27">pagename</a>
```

the link above goes to a page where the link is counted and it looks for the url into the database and redirects to that page. But i want to see which user clicked it.

Comment: Can you at least show us the HTML you are using and what you have tried so far? StackOverflow is meant to help you with code you've already attempted rather than writing it all for you.

Answer (score 1):

Most easiest way would be to pass a `link-identifier` as the URI parameter

An example:

```
<a href="page.php?id=27&clicked=pagename">pagename</a>
```

Now you can get what the user clicked by checking `$_GET['clicked']`

---

It seems I misunderstood the question

You can do this on your `page.php`

```
$id = $_GET['id']; //Get the page id
$userid = $_SESSION['id']; // Get the user id if stored in session

//Do something with the user id

header("location: ..."); //redirect to a different place
exit;
```

Comment: Correct and you can use the session to get the id of the logged in user

Comment: What do you mean by adding my point to your answer? I don't understand

Comment: @chchrist, You added to my answer, so I wanted you to edit my answer and keep the pointed, so that it will be stated as your contribution to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of linking to `http://www.google.com/` for example, link to:

`redirect.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F`

In redirect.php, you `INSERT` your record into the database and do something like:

```
 header("Location: ".$_GET['href']);
```

Comment: Ya i can count the link but want to see which user clicked it.

Comment: @Starx: Please note the "for example" in the first line of my answer.

Comment: ya i understood the FOR EXAMPLE but I have already done that part. I want to see which user actually clicked the link

Comment: I don't know how your login system works. Can you give some details about that?